# labeling specific scatter points in matplotlib legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to add 'blue scat' to the legend of this graph without rewriting everything underlying the graph creation.  I was able to specify 'red bar' and 'blue bar' without having four entries in the legend by labeling the artists directly via `patches[0]` and `patches[1]`, but I can't find a way to do the same with a scatter plot.  [`legend_elements()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PathCollection.legend_elements) sounded promising, but I can't get anything useful out of it.
[image: sample chart]

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.axes import Axes as ax

df = pd.DataFrame({'barVals':[5, 10, 15, 20], 'scatVals':[7, 12, 17, 22], 'color':['red', 'blue', 'red', 'blue']})
df

bar = plt.bar(range(len(df)), df['barVals'], color=df['color'], alpha=0.7)
sc = plt.scatter(range(len(df)), df['scatVals'], s=20, c=df['color'])

plt.legend((bar.patches[0], bar.patches[1], sc), ('red bar', 'blue bar', 'red scat', 'blue scat'), scatterpoints=1)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use proxy artists for legend creation.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame({'barVals':[5, 10, 15, 20], 'scatVals':[7, 12, 17, 22], 'color':['red', 'blue', 'red', 'blue']})

bar = plt.bar(range(len(df)), df['barVals'], color=df['color'], alpha=0.7)
sc = plt.scatter(range(len(df)), df['scatVals'], s=20, c=df['color'])

proxys = [plt.Line2D([],[], marker="o", ms=5, ls="", color=c) for c in ['red', 'blue']]
plt.legend((bar.patches[0], bar.patches[1], *proxys), ('red bar', 'blue bar', 'red scat', 'blue scat'), scatterpoints=1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I need to read up on that more to fully understand what's going on, but it worked perfectly.  Thanks!